# Removing data structure

Tags: python, data-structures, list-manipulation

The goal here is to take an amount of int values indicated by the first int and create a list, in order of even numbers to odd numbers (value order of the numbers doesn't matter).

My code so far deals with most of the problem. However, how would I go about ignoring the first int value?

Example input:

```
example=[7,1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]                            
example=[3,3, 3, 2]                                                    
example=[3,2, 2, 2]
```

My code:

```
even=[]
odd=[]

while True:
    try:
        n = int(input())
    except:
        break

    if  n % 2 ==0:
        even.append(n)

    else:
        odd.append(n)

print(even+odd)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you **expect** that script to do and where it does not work yet how it should?

Comment: @NicoHaase Sorry you didn't see the clarity in the question. Essentially the first number of each int was a value that indicated how many trailing int values would follow. I managed to make a pretty simple odd/even sorting program but it wasn't able to deal with removing the initial int value when sorting. Muhammad Umair answered the question pretty precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before going in while loop, pop out first value. You can also save this as the total numbers.

Also, there is an error in your code. If try fails in while loop, for the first time loop running there will be an exception. And next on previous value will be used, so a single value will be repeated. I corrected it by adding `n=0`.

```
even=[]
odd=[]

n=0

NumCount= int(input())

while True:
    try:
        n = int(input())
    except:
        break

    if  n % 2 ==0:
        even.append(n)

    else:
        odd.append(n)

print ("Total numbers (even+odd)", NumCount)

print(even+odd)
```

Comment: @Ryan see the answer again, I have edited and added an error correction in the answer.